# Selecting a WP_Post Object value (if it has) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have this example array/object:

```
//$monday array values
Array (
[menu_item1] => 
[menu_item2] =>
Array (
[0] =>
WP_Post Object (
[ID] => 530 
[post_content] => Food selection 2 
[post_title] => Food 2 ) )
```

I'm beginner in `WP_Post Objects`. How can I get the `menu_item1` `ID` (if it has value) and `menu_item2` `ID` value (if it has too)?

[The documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) isn't helped me.

I'm sure it's something like but it doesn't work:

```
foreach ($monday as $key => $value) {
    if ($value) {
        $myid = $value->ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any error report?

Comment: Try `$myid = $value[0]->ID;`

Comment: @HerryPotei Potei nothing returns, no error

Comment: @Erwin yes it worked. My problem it doesn't check if the value empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments( @Erwin ).

```
foreach ($monday as $key => $value) {
    if ($value) {
        $myid = $value[0]->ID; // this way you can access to object and get id
    }
}
```

Checking:

```
foreach ($monday as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) { //checking all values to not be empty
        if(!empty($value[0])){ //checking, if exists something where you have id
            $myid = $value[0]->ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can double check in second statement to get only objects:

```
foreach ($monday as $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($value)) { 
        if(!empty($value[0]) && is_object($value[0])){ 
            $myid = $value[0]->ID;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, remember. If sort of your array will changed, then the code above will not gave you result as expected.